# Grouped query for find only one record (employee_id = 1 or null)

Tags: mysql, sql

My db info is
 [image]

I wont to get for each weekday unique record if employee_id has value that record, else employee_id is Null.
I try this query

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  `calendar` 
WHERE `employee_id` = 1 
  OR `employee_id` IS NULL 
GROUP BY `weekday`
```

result is

[image]

But I expect

[image]

Can you help me? Thanks

Comment: `SELECT * FROM ... GROUP BY ...` What could get wrong? [GROUP BY contributes the most confusion](https://blog.jooq.org/2016/12/09/a-beginners-guide-to-the-true-order-of-sql-operations/) and `"note, unfortunately, MySQL users that do not use the STRICT mode will still get a result here with arbitrary last names!, so a new MySQL user won’t understand their mistake"`

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
SELECT 
  b.calendar_id,
  a.employee_id,
  a.weekday 
FROM
  (SELECT 
    `weekday`,
    MAX(employee_id) AS employee_id 
  FROM
    calendar 
  WHERE employee_id = 1 
    OR employee_id IS NULL 
  GROUP BY `weekday`) a 
  LEFT JOIN calendar b 
    ON a.weekday = b.weekday 
    AND a.employee_id = b.employee_id ;
```

Let me know in case of any clarifications.

Comment: Thanks.
Only ask table name is calendar not `calender`

Comment: oh yes. i changed that. Your got the logic, my work is done :)

Comment: No problem, Just an advice, never post pictures. post datasets, as in write them, so that the one who is trying to solve for your problem can directly copy that. I guess one the reasons your question is getting so many downvotes is because of that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171880/discussion-between-davit-and-g-arima).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you have columns in the list after `SELECT`, that don't appear in the `GROUP BY` expression nor have an aggregate function applied to them. MySQL, in contrast to most other DBMS, allows this in older versions (or with certain settings) but the results are likely to be garbage.

Fix this by including the columns in the `GROUP BY` expression or by applying an aggregate function on them. For example:

```
SELECT max(`employee_id`),
       `weekday`
       FROM `calendar` 
       WHERE `employee_id` = 1 
              OR `employee_id` IS NULL 
       GROUP BY `weekday`;
```

Note the `max()` aggregate function on `employee_id`.

Comment: SELECT MAX(`employee_id`),
       `weekday`, `calendar_id` 
       FROM `calendar` 
       WHERE `employee_id` = 1 
              OR `employee_id` IS NULL 
       GROUP BY `weekday`;

Comment: Try this query and you can notice result is not need

Comment: @david your query doesnot work because you applied group by on weekday. so you have to take all the columns in select statement which can be grouped. Since calender id is not grouped (should not be), therefore it doesnot work