# SQL Group code bugs

Tags: sql, sql-server

In this very small code, it keeps telling me that somethings wrong around "Group", but in my oppinion the code is very right?

```
      SELECT
    grades.PERSON_ID, grades.GRADE, 
    students.PERSON_ID, students.ENROLL_PERIOD, students.FACULTY_ID
FROM  
    students 
INNER JOIN 
    grades ON students.PERSON_ID = grades.PERSON_ID 
WHERE 
    GRADE = '00' or
    GRADE ='-3' or
    GRADE ='U' or
    GRADE ='SY' or
    GRADE ='IA' or
    GRADE ='NI'
GROUP BY
    students.PERSON_ID
ORDER BY 
    students.PERSON_ID;
```

Comment: change this `GRADE ='NI' or` to this `GRADE ='NI'`

Comment: Let me guess, MySQL background? If yes then same as: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50555575/grouped-query-for-find-only-one-record-employee-id-1-or-null#comment88121933_50555575

Comment: Also, change this `students.PERSON_ID,` to `students.PERSON_ID`

Comment: Why are you grouping at all, if you are not using aggregate functions?

Comment: So like now? Edited it

Comment: HoneyBadger what do you mean? I need to find the STUDENT_ID with the most of the 'WHERE' grades in. Do you have a good way to that?

Comment: "Most" suggests the use of the `MAX()` function, why do you not use it?

Comment: You need a aggregate function to find the "most". your query gives information about all students. Try with `COUNT` which would give the number

Comment: Hi again HoneyBadger and Abhishek. Is one of you able to tell me where to put it?

Comment: @Adem . . . Provide sample data and desired results to clarify what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using an aggregate function with column then all those are in select should be in the group by clause. Group by Means grouping against column/Columns

```
SELECT
        grades.PERSON_ID, grades.GRADE, 
        students.PERSON_ID, students.ENROLL_PERIOD, students.FACULTY_ID
    FROM  
        students 
    INNER JOIN 
        grades ON students.PERSON_ID = grades.PERSON_ID 
    WHERE 
        GRADE = '00' or
        GRADE ='-3' or
        GRADE ='U' or
        GRADE ='SY' or
        GRADE ='IA' or
        GRADE ='NI'
    GROUP BY
        grades.PERSON_ID, grades.GRADE, 
        students.PERSON_ID, students.ENROLL_PERIOD, students.FACULTY_ID
    ORDER BY 
        students.PERSON_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an aggregate function to find out max grade from each group. 
Try this.

```
SELECT
    students.PERSON_ID, Max(grades.GRADE) As Max_GRADE
FROM  
    students 
INNER JOIN 
    grades ON students.PERSON_ID = grades.PERSON_ID 
WHERE 
    GRADE = '00' or
    GRADE ='-3' or
    GRADE ='U' or
    GRADE ='SY' or
    GRADE ='IA' or
    GRADE ='NI'
GROUP BY
    students.PERSON_ID
ORDER BY 
    students.PERSON_ID;
```

Comment: Column 'grades.PERSON_ID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause... What is the reason for this?

Comment: It doesnt seem to find the PERSON_ID with the highest quantity of the grades? It just lists all PERSON_ID's with there belonging grades

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you don't want aggregation at all . . . Just students who have one of these grades.

Your query can be simplified in three ways:

- Table aliases
- `IN`
- Not including `PERSON_ID` twice in the result set

So, try writing it as:

```
SELECT s.PERSON_ID, g.GRADE, s.ENROLL_PERIOD, s.FACULTY_ID
FROM students s INNER JOIN 
     grades g
     ON s.PERSON_ID = g.PERSON_ID 
WHERE g.GRADE IN ('00', '-3', 'U', 'SY', 'IA', 'NI')
ORDER BY s.PERSON_ID;
```

If you want one arbitrary row per `PERSON_ID` (as suggested by your mis-use of `GROUP BY`), you can use a SQL Server trick:

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES . . .
. . . 
ORDER BY RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY s.PERSON_ID ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
```